# How to Host Dot Net Nuke Web Site on IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, friendly-url, dotnetnuke-7

I am Facing some problem while hosting Dot Net Nuke Site. I dont know how dot Net Nuke works, I never work on DNN.

We have Old Dot Net Nuke Website Hosted on Server under domain name ABC.com/XX
And now want host that site under separate domain.
We got domain name XYZ.com and I have created new Web Site in IIS and place all Old Source code in XYZ.com. Now when I tried to access XYZ.com i am getting error
404- File or Directory not found.

I think I am missing some setting for URL Writing.I don't know about previous setting, Someone host this website long ago and don't have any documentation.

can you tell me how to do this/what setting i have to do.

Answer (score 1):

First, depending on your configuration, you may have to get the sql server database too.
Look at the connection strings in your web.config should indicate what database was used.
If it looks like "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;", the database files are stored in the website folder. You only have to configure the datasource parameter with the name of the local instance of SQL Server if it's installed on it.
Otherwise, you have to get the database, configure it in your SQL Server and modify those connection strings.
Then, I suggest you to add an entry in the PortalAlias table of this database with the new domain you want to use. In your post, I guess it could be "XYZ.com".
I hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.
The thing is i am directly copying all source code to new domain including web config So it should work directly i have also change old domain name from port Alias to new one.